# Laravel make settings for store

Tags: php, laravel, settings

I have an online store in laravel 5.4 and I want to make configurable settings in the admin panel (stuff like store name, phone number, email, store address etc.).

I am using a database for now and the fields are always the same (store name, phone...) so I will always be using only one row in the settings table.

My question is because I will use only one row is there any better way to set those settings for example in file and which is better.

Answer (score 2):

Why change it when you are doing it on the correct way?

Database storage gives you easy accessibility to the data and a lot of security by default.

I would recommend **always** to use a database instead of a file for storing data, specially if there is some *vulnerable* information, files should be used when you want to store some configuration of the app, like environment, modules, locales...